# Rotate object relative to its current rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script which makes a cube move around and rotate like a plane, But I want it to rotate relative to its current rotation.

```cs
 int movementSpeed = 2;
    public float rotspeed = 3f;
    public Rigidbody force;
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        force.AddForce (transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            force.AddTorque(0, rotspeed, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            force.AddTorque(0, rotspeed*-1, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            force.AddTorque(rotspeed, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            force.AddTorque(rotspeed * -1 , 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
```

If i were to rotate my plane upward, and then press "a" or "d" i would want to rotate it just left or right, but instead it attempts to rotate as if i were upright.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to `transform.rotation` and `transform.localRotation` there also exist two different methods for applying forces/torques to RigidBodies:

Instead of using [`Rigidbody.AddTorque`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html) which takes a

> `torque`: Torque vector **in world coordinates**.

and therefore rotates in global world space you would rather want to use [`Rigidbody.AddTorqueRelative`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque.html) which takes a

> `torque`: Torque vector in **local coordinates**.

and

> Adds a `torque` to the `Rigidbody` **relative to its coordinate system**.

```c#
force.AddForceRelative (Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

if (Input.GetKey("d"))
{
    force.AddTorqueRelative(0, rotspeed, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
if (Input.GetKey("a"))
{
    force.AddTorqueRelative(0, -rotspeed, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
if (Input.GetKey("w"))
{
    force.AddTorqueRelative(rotspeed, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
if (Input.GetKey("s"))
{
    force.AddTorqueRelative(-rotspeed, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AddRelativeTorque instead of AddTorque.